# No PSB pin on LCD?

Tags: arduino, spi, lcd, wiring

I bought a Winstar 144x32 LCD (WG14432D) because it was cheap and it would be nice to do some experiments with it. The main problem with this LCD is that it has no (working) library for it.

I already searched the whole Internet with Google, but my results were unimpressive:

https://forum.crystalfontz.com/showthread.php/7410-Tutorial-ST7920-Seeeduino-v4-2-Arduino-Sample-Sketch-Driving-a-144x32-Graphic-LCD (A huge example code which doesn't work. I set SCK, MISO and CS correctly and nothing happens.)

Knowing it has the *ST7920* chip, I found a library for screens that use this same chip: https://github.com/olikraus/u8glib/wiki/device#st7920-192x32
(The library supports only other resolutions, such as 128x64, but I think as it's the same chip, it should work too. I also tried other screen variants of this same chip.)

On some portuguese site I found how to initialize and use the library properly:
http://www.arduinoecia.com.br/2013/09/display-grafico-lcd-128x64-st7920.html (No problem for me, as I speak portuguese too)

They use: `U8GLIB_ST7920_128X64_1X u8g(6, 5, 4 ,7);` to set the software SPI pins for the LCD. On mine (Arduino Mega) it would be:

```
U8GLIB_ST7920_128X64_1X u8g(52, 51, 53); //Enable, RW, RS [,RESET] (known also as) SCK, MOSI, CS
```

The result: The display stayed blank. Then I tried to use the hardware SPI initialization, which according to [this site](https://github.com/olikraus/u8glib/wiki/device#additional-information) is: `U8GLIB_ST7920_128X64_1X u8g(53); // RS (known also as) CS pin needed only`

Even so, the display won't do anything. It stayed light gray (Contrast adjusted) and that's it. No blinking, no switching on/off, nothing...

Finally, I was reading on [this datasheet](https://img.ozdisan.com/ETicaret_Dosya/381288_2815202.pdf) that the PSB pin must be set to 0 (ground) in order to enable SPI mode.

[image: PSB Pin must be set to zero]

Other variants of those screen had jumpers or pins on the back, which you can jump to ground, but this one has none.

A high resolution image of the back of the LCD I captured (or atleast tried) and attached below (the front has nothing but the LCD), because I could find *nothing* about anything of this board. No schematic, nothing.

[image: Back of the WG14432D]

I couldn't find any PSB pin (which is identified as it), jumper ("JP") or similar on this board.

The pins to interface the LCD had no unusual pins which are identified as "PSB" or similar too:

[image: Pins on the WG14432D]

Any suggestion or answer is much appreciated.

Comment: The moral of the story is never buy any electronic component or dev kit that doesn't come with proper documentation. The usual result of buying the cheapest bit of knock-off electronics you can find is you spend ages trying to figure out how it works, and then eventually give up and buy a properly documented one.

Comment: I don't think "Winstar" is a knockoff, as it's the only that has a 144x32 lcd.

Comment: Have a look at this [AliExpress page](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/122x32-Graphic-Dot-Matrix-LCD-Module-controller-IC-st7920-blue-white-Universal-LCD/1440017691.html): Most likely SCKL should be connected to pin 6 (E), MOSI to pin 5 (R/W), SS to pin 4 (RS) and MISO is probably not used.

Comment: @Fusseldieb To be honest I didn't look up Winstar to find out. But you'd be surprised how many companies sell the exact same part. For example there is a company seemingly without a website called aMtec who sell the same display. There are lots of such companies hidden away behind well presented front companies. They all sell the same products and the reason the documentation is so bad is that they are just repackaging the rubbish docs they were given. The thing that is a dead give away is the lack of any company name printed on the PCB.

Comment: @Codo I know the pinout from this site: https://github.com/olikraus/u8glib/wiki/device#additional-information , but thanks.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Probably that's why nobody uses those displays for Arduino and stuff. They have no (working) library, no (good) documentation, nothing... It's sad.

Comment: @Fusseldieb: Cool to see you got it working. May I suggest you use the u8g2 library. It's the successor to u8g. The constructor `U8G2_ST7920_192X32_F_SW_SPI ` should work and be a better fit regarding the size (correct height, slightly too wide).

Comment: @Codo Thanks, but I have no need to use u8g2 for now, as I modified the u8g to fit the 144x32 LCD (Made funcions for that particular LCD, adjusted HW SPI speed [corrupted screen content - was too fast], etc). I can't upload it to GitHub because I honestly am confused on how contribution works there, but anyway...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Many LCD controllers (including the ST7920) can support a variety of interface types, of which you can use one at a time. Sometimes the interface type is *fixed* on a given LCD display module; sometimes the interface can be selected. The exact PCB markings for selecting between interfaces (when possible) does not always match the signal names you are expecting.

Since the interface is not *always* able to be selected, then the answer from *Finbarr* is sometimes correct - you might find that the interface is absolutely fixed (e.g. parallel-only, SPI-only etc.) on a given LCD module.

However in your case, I think you *might* be lucky. I noticed a similarity between your LCD module, and the one used in the first tutorial which you linked.

Notice how your LCD module has the part number `14432D` on the back, and we see 2 component locations - `R11` and `R12`. `R11` is missing and `R12` is fitted:

[image: Back of original LCD display - R11 missing, R12 fitted]

Now look at this image from the first tutorial that you linked, showing the back of *that* LCD module (which is different to *your* LCD module, and hence there is no guarantee that the first tutorial you linked would apply to your LCD module anyway). See that it has the same component arrangement as your LCD module and also has an `R11` and `R12`. Except on *that* module, `R11` is fitted and `R12` is missing:

[image: LCD module PCB from tutorial showing R11 fitted, R12 missing]

I cannot *guarantee* that this next part applies to your LCD module - you need *its* datasheet with the relevant details to be completely sure. However it is possible that the answer is contained in [this document](https://www.crystalfontz.com/products/document/3537/ST7920_Interface_Selection.pdf):

[image: LCD interface selection options]

Notice how for *their* model number ending **14432D** (similar to your model number), the resistors `R11` and `R12` are used to select between parallel and SPI interfaces. On the LCD module in your first tutorial link, see how only `R11` is fitted, and they are using the SPI interface. On *your* LCD module, see how only `R12` is fitted and you are unable to use the SPI interface pinout as shown in that tutorial.

So perhaps your LCD module is configured for a parallel interface? That would be consistent with the fact that `R12` is fitted on your LCD module.

**Therefore *perhaps* by desoldering `R12` from your board and resoldering it in the `R11` position, you may be able to use the SPI interface and pinout shown in that first tutorial.**

---

Update:

Here is the PCB after *Fusseldieb* made the modification (the resistor was moved from the `R12` position, to the `R11` position):

[image: Original LCD after moving resistor from R12 position to R11 position]

That modification was confirmed to **successfully** enable the SPI interface, using the following connector pins:

```
LCD Pin   SPI signal   (Original)
-------   ----------   ----------
   1        Vdd          (Vdd)
   2        Vss          (Vss)
   3        Vo           (Vo)
   4        CS (SS)      (RS)
   5        MOSI         (R/W)
   6        SCLK         (E)
```

---

FYI, looking at the other tutorial:

http://www.arduinoecia.com.br/2013/09/display-grafico-lcd-128x64-st7920.html

That uses an LCD module with a completely different interface pinout, which includes the `CS1` and `CS2` signals (pins 15 & 16 on its 20-pin connector). This allows the interface to be switched between parallel and SPI without needing to solder/desolder components on the PCB. You don't have that 20-pin connector with those signals on your LCD module. That is why that tutorial does not directly apply to your module (although the ST7920 *commands* will likely apply, once you can get an SPI interface working on *your* specific LCD module).

Comment: Now **that's** an elaborated answer. Thank you so much for your time. As I can't use the LCD this way anyways, I'll try to solder the resistor as you said. I'll reply later.

Comment: @Fusseldieb - You're welcome :-)  "*I'll try to solder the resistor as you said*" OK. It might already be clear, but since you didn't mention the desoldering which is involved first, I'll just summarise: The modification is to *desolder* `R12` before you then solder that same component into the `R11` location on the PCB. You can't get away without removing `R12` ;-) If you have a problem doing that desoldering of `R12` (I don't know what tools & experience you have) then there is an alternative (but higher-risk) approach. Let me know if I need to explain it. Good luck!

Comment: Done. Have I soldered it right? http://prntscr.com/gjvd6o (Sorry for almost killing that tiny resistor :P)

Comment: @Fusseldieb - As long as the right-hand side of `R11` is properly soldered to its pad (I'm not sure from the photo) then yes, that looks correct to me :-)

Comment: No wayyy... **LOOK**: http://prntscr.com/gjvhqk Hug me! *NOW!*

Comment: @Fusseldieb - That's excellent news. I think that counts as success. Well done!

Comment: You sir, deserve two medals. One for being a superhero right now and the other just in case you loose the first one. Wow! Finally those LCD's will be useful for a lot of people. You can't imagine my happyness right now. Seriously. Thank you so much. :-)

Comment: @Fusseldieb - I'm speechless, thanks. :-) Isn't it great when some hardware hacking works :-) Thanks also for supplying all the photos and links on the first place! To help future readers, I'll update my answer to include your photo of the PCB after you moved the resistor, so that they know how it should look to enable the SPI interface option. Again, well done & good luck!

Comment: Totally nice! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, you're stuck with a parallel interface on that display. The controller IC itself supports the choice between a serial or parallel interface but the pin is hardwired to 1 on the PCB.

The smallest interface you can use would be 7 bits: RS, R/W, E and four data lines.

Comment: But then why are the header pins labeled as if they are supporting SPI? (RS, R/W, E)? Also, the example code has a video to it which shows the (exact?) same LCD in action over SPI, with the same wiring as mine.

Comment: SPI would have pins labelled SCLK, MOSI, MISO and possibly SS.

Comment: I have used Chinese displays in the past. And even though the pins had strange labels, they supported SPI. You just have to find out which is which...

Comment: @Codo I already triplechecked the pins. I know which one is MISO, CLK, CS... But no matter what, it will not work.